# Why can't i call remove() on Gtk::EventBox?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

For some reason that is beyond me this doesn't work:

```
Gtk::EventBox *eb;
// ...
eb->foreach([eb](Gtk::Widget& w){ eb->remove(w); });
```

The error that i am getting is:

```
ImageClick.cpp: In lambda function:
ImageClick.cpp:20:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::EventBox::remove(Gtk::Widget&)’
    eb->foreach([eb](Gtk::Widget& w){ eb->remove(w); });
                                                  ^
ImageClick.cpp:20:50: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/window.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/dialog.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/aboutdialog.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h:99,
                 from ImageClick.cpp:1:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/bin.h:141:8: note: void Gtk::Bin::remove()
   void remove();
        ^
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/bin.h:141:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

But if i change it to `eb->Gtk::Container::remove(w);` it works as expected. Documentation shows that Gtk::EventBox is a subclass of Gtk::Container, and it is not a virtual function, nor is it overwritten anywhere. So what is the reason for such a behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"?

Comment: @LogicStuff Correct, i should have made it more clear. Edited the question and added the error message.

Comment: I'm not a GTK person but `Gtk::EventBox` probably declares `remove` but doesn't provide an overload that takes a `Gtk::Widget`. If so it won't pick up the declarations in the base class during name resolution (Google member hiding) and you'll have to provide a fully qualified name like the solution you found or change your lambda to take a `Gtk::Container` as its argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is a normal operation of C++

**container.h**

```
virtual void on_remove(Widget* widget);
```

**bin.h**

```
void remove();
```

and **eventbox.h** doesn't have this function defined.

Trying to recreate this scenario:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void foo(int) { std::cout << 'A' << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << 'B' << std::endl; }
};

class C : public B
{
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.foo(5);
}
```

The code above generates the exact same error. It appears that the name stops any further lookup. I was aware of shadowning, but didn't know this has happened when the shadowing function actually doesn't fit even with all the thunks in the world.